# Pointing variables at other variables in c#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Is it possible to have one variable point to another variable for shortcut purposes? For instance, let's say I have a variable in one class that is called `SharedResources.proxTelescope`, how do I get a variable in another class called `prox` to point to the first variable, in a sort of shortcut type of thing. I could just do `var prox = SharedResources.proxTelescope;`, but if proxTelescope changes, it won't reflect on prox, will it? How should I do it instead.

Comment: What do you mean by changes?  If the properties or variables of proxTelescope change, it will also change in prox.  If the assignment of proxTelescope itself changes, however, then it will now be a different object from prox.

Comment: Yeah, I mean the assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would set things up as a property.

```
private <type> prox
{
    get { return SharedResources.proxTelescope; }
    set { SharedResources.proxTelescope = value }
}
```

Comment: at least using this method you aren't relying on nebulous and non-specific references for the linking.  Declaring it as a class property is clearer and easier to both read and maintain.  it is, however, less efficient and a minor cause of code bloat.  its all about what you want to accomplish really.

Comment: Ok, I'll accept the one with less rep. Thanks, not sure why I didn't think of this. "You can accept an answer in 7 minutes."

Comment: This should work assuming the property is of a reference type.  A value type property is not so clear cut.  Mutable structs do weird things.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a property, something like:

```
public YourTypeHere prox
{
    get { return SharedResources.proxTelescope; }
    set { SharedResources.proxTelescope = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the variables are classes then they are reference type, so any change in one of them will be reflected in the other.

If the variables are structs, then they are value types and you have a problem, you can make some function(or property) to get the value.

Comment: But if one of the reference variables gets set to something different, it won't be reflected in the others, right.

Comment: @ArlenBeiler Correct. If the proxTelescope gets reassigned, then it is no longer reflected in the others.

Comment: I agree, i assumed he won't assign it to point to another object, only will change the object he already references to.

Answer (score 0):

If the value should be 'shared' among all instances, then it would probably be best to have the variable exist as a static member of the class it is on, and create an instance property that retreives the value of the static variable.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use a `Func<T>`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Func<DesiredType> ValueGetter {get;set;}
    public DesiredType Value { get { return ValueGetter(); } }
}
```

This can then by used this way:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.ValueGetter = () => SharedResources.proxTelescope;

var value = myClass.Value;
```